# Migrating table with PutDatabaseRecord with different column name at the target table

Tags: apache-nifi

I need to migrate the data from a db2 table to a mssql table but one column has a different name, but the same datatype.

Db2 table:
NROCTA,NUMRUT,DIASMORA2

MSSQL table:
NROCTA,NUMRUT,DIAMORAS

As you see DIAMORAS is different.

Im using the following flow:

ExecuteSQL -> SplitAvro -> PutDatabaseRecord

In PutDataBaseRecord I have as RecordReader an AvroReader configured in this way:

Schema Acesss Strategy: Use Embedded Avro Schema.
Schema Text: ${avro.schema}

The flow just insert the two first columns.¿How I can do the mapping between DIASMORA2 and DIAMORAS columns ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you probably don't need SplitAvro in your flow at all, unless there's some logical subset of rows that you are trying to send as individual transactions.

For the column name change, use UpdateRecord and set the field `/DIASMORAS` to the record path `/DIASMORA2`, and change the name of the field in the AvroRecordSetWriter's schema from `DIASMORA2` to `DIASMORAS`.

That last part is a little trickier since you are using the embedded schema in your AvroReader. If the schema will always be the same, you can stop the UpdateRecord processor and put in an ExtractAvroMetadata processor to extract the `avro.schema` attribute. That will put the embedded schema in the flowfile's `avro.schema` attribute.

Then before you start UpdateRecord, start the ExecuteSQL and ExtractAvroMetadata processors, then inspect a flow file in the queue to copy the schema out of the `avro.schema` attribute. Then in your AvroRecordSetWriter in ConvertRecord, instead of Inheriting the schema, you can choose to `Use Schema Text`, then paste in the schema from the attribute, changing `DIASMORA2` to `DIASMORAS`. This approach puts values from the `DIASMORA2` field into the `DIASMORAS` field, but since `DIASMORA2` is not in the output schema, it is ignored, thereby effectively renaming the field (although under the hood it is a copy-and-remove).

Comment: Thanks mattyb for your answer!  I'm using SplitAvro (with Output Size = 1) because if there are some records that cause errors in the insert, then no records will be inserted, not even the good ones (Is there any other way to solve this?). However using PutDataBaseRecord with SplitAvro is less efficient, it takes longer. I can resolve my problem putting in the query "select DIASMORA2 AS DIAMORAS" so the avro schema matches perfectly with column names in the table.